# Running model on full dataset or just test set?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, modeling, boosting, train-test-split

I'm new to using XGBoost and I'm confused about how we should obtain the XGBoost predicted values for each data point. For example, the process for fitting and evaluating an XGBoost model is:

```
# STEP 1: Splitting dataframe between target variable and predictor variables
X = df.drop(['Target'], 1)
y = df['Target']

# STEP 2: Splitting the data into training (80%) & test sets (20%)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# STEP 3: Initiating XGBoost Regression model
model = xgb.XGBRegressor()

# STEP 4: Fitting model to training data
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# STEP 5: Generating Predictions on test set
y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)

# STEP 6: Generating test set RMSE
rmse_test = np.sqrt(MSE(y_test, y_pred_test))
print("RMSE: %f" % (rmse_test))
```

At this point, we have our model and have evaluated the model performance.
If we then wanted to obtain the model predictions for each data point (i.e. a table showing each row and columns of the actual target variable and the predicted target variable), **would we run the model on the full data set `X`? Or only on the test set?** Slightly confused here so any help would be appreciated?

Comment: When you say "run the model on the full data set", do you mean making predictions, or do you also mean training a model on everything before making predictions using that model that was trained on everything?

Comment: Hi @Dave, by "run the model on the full data set" I mean making predictions. I'm slightly confused by how this works exactly

Comment: If you want to make a prediction for a set of feature values, then you have to apply the model to those feature values. Consequently, if you want predictions for points that are in the training data, you must apply your model to those points.

Comment: @Dave What I don't understand is when we make predictions on the test set, aren't we missing out on all the predictions for the data points in the training set? Sorry for the stupid question just trying to understand this a bit better

Comment: You do, so apply the model to the other points you want to predict. (Why you care about this is a separate issue.)

Comment: If I had a dataset of student's test scores between 0-100, and I was only interested in those student's with scores between 70-80, could I train a model on the full dataset (every score 0-100) and predict on the subset (70-80)?